# how to disable dates till current date?

Tags: android, android-calendar

How to disable date in calendar till current date in android

```
editText_Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date dates = c.getTime();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mDayName = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(dates.getTime());
            System.out.println("mDayName = "+mDayName);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Create_slots.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    //editText_Date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year); //'dd-mm-yyy'
                    editText_Date.setText(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth); //'yyy-mm-dd'
                    date1 =  editText_Date.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("date1 = "+date1);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

This above code disables past date from current date.. i want to disable dates till current date. need help.

Comment: datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);

Comment: You are already using datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000); na what was issue

Comment: @Rudresh that line disables only dates before current date.. I want to disable all previous dates till current date

Comment: Try this datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
     DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Create_slots.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                //editText_Date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year); //'dd-mm-yyy'
                editText_Date.setText(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth); //'yyy-mm-dd'
                date1 =  editText_Date.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("date1 = "+date1);

            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();   
        mcurrentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly like i wanted..
Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();   
        mcurrentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis());

Answer (score 0):

Solution:You will use the Date picker and set the code as below

```
DatePicker datePicker = date.getDatePicker();
datePicker.setMinDate(d.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Library for Date and Time Picking

```
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
```

Documentation can be found here:

[Material Date Time Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

Here you can limit time picker or date picker

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   editText_Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar minimum = Calendar.getInstance();
         minimum.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
         minimum.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
         minimum.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
         minimum.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
        Date dates = c.getTime();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mDayName = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(dates.getTime());
        System.out.println("mDayName = "+mDayName);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Create_slots.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {       
                //editText_Date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year); //'dd-mm-yyy'
                editText_Date.setText(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth); //'yyy-mm-dd'
                date1 =  editText_Date.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("date1 = "+date1);

            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minimum.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Just copy this whole code, might save you today.
Credit [Dimitri Borohhov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5707212/dmitri-borohhov)